# how to change Bootstrap navbar link style custom? change hover link border color.?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below image show the custom navbar style which I want to customise.
[Custom style should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8spuD.png)

I tried this CSS for customisation but not gives me proper styling

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .dropdown.open a:focus {
   text-align: center;
   color: #286090;
   border-bottom: 3px solid red;
   background-color: #fff;
  }
```

thank in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This platform is not supposed as programming service but rather to support you and give you hints regarding specific issues.

Comment: @Lepidopteron: I'm new to bootstrap, I tried to set navbar-default, nav list border-bottom but its not work for me. I just want On hover or On click,  Drop-down links top-border Red as I attached Image above.